# How much time to dry hop and why?

Tags: hops, dry-hop, ipa, beer-styles

I'm thinking about brewing an IPA.
My doubt is about "short dry hopping"  vs "length dry hopping" I am thinking to go for 2 days minimum and 7 days maximum.
I want to know your opinions and experiences about this.

A link with a experiment about that:

http://brulosophy.com/2015/10/26/dry-hop-length-long-vs-short-exbeeriment-results/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm with everyone else. 5-7 days.

To get that super hoppy aroma though, I've only been able to get that by using a hop back with first-wort and dry-hopping (clone W. Coast ipa, greenflash). For less than $30 I built a hop back and filtered the wort through loose leaf hops of the same or similar variety I was already pellet-hopping, just prior to chilling, pitching and fermenting.

Here's the general idea I built mine from - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oencb.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Trial and error.

There is no definite answer. I haven't achieved yet great aroma, so far dry hopped in primary in last couple days. I would add 5 oz per 10gl.

Read an article saying its better to dry hop it in keg or closed vessel. Aromas can escape with CO2.

Answer (score 0):

You want your beer to be hoppy-fresh... Unfortunately, hoppy profile fades away with time. I'm not sure at what rate, but trust me, there is a difference in freshly brewed IPA (brewery fresh) vs the 1 or 2 month old. If you save couple of bottles for the future, you can compare.

So, usually when you look at the recipes, it says to dry-hop it in last 5-7. That should be sufficient for regular IPA to extract some hoppy chemicals and produce hoppy aroma. If you don't filter your beer, it will bring some haziness to it, which is totally acceptable by the style.

Comment: Thanks for your comment red, but i dont want to age my beer just want to Know how much time dry hop if 2,3 or 7 days read my link please

Comment: That's why I said, that 5-7 days should be sufficient enough. It is a usual recommended time for IPAs. In case if somebody else is reading your question and has similar concerns, but for different type of beer, I included a first portion of the answer. In reality this is not a simple answer. It depends on what hops you're using, and what are you looking for. Personally I prefer West Coast IPAs and I would do 5-7 days with aggressive hops. If I had to brew something for East Coast competition, I would do it for 3-5 with less aggressive hops.

Comment: "Aggressive hops" aren't really a factor here. You're not getting alpha acids when you dry hop. So, there "power" is mostly subjective/based on the flavor profile.

Answer (score 0):

YMMV, but when we do it, we'll actually wait until primary is nearly finished before dry hopping. If you move to secondary, you could actually pull it off the yeast cake for re-use without getting a ton of hops stuck in your yeast.

4-7 days is good at the end of primary/beginning of secondary should get you want you're after. If you're looking for a HUGE punch of aroma, then 3-4 oz (in 5 g). A regular nice nose is what you'll generally see for 1-2 oz/5g.

Vinnie Cilurzo from Russian River actually recommends two different dry hopping periods for an IIPA (once early and once late), but for a single, one 4-7 day period should do it.

Drinking it fresh will be better than waiting.

Answer (score 0):

You should be get a pretty good hop aroma with just dry hopping for the last couple of days in primary. That's always been my plan of attack and it's worked well compared to dry hopping at other periods of primary.

Comment: so dry hop on primarty or secondary ?

Comment: Even if your planning on moving to secondary I would still dry hop in primary, just make sure fermentation is done (or almost done).

Comment: The problem with dry-hopping in primary is then you can't reuse the yeast because hops are mixed in with it. For those using expensive liquid yeast that can be reused 10 times its best to transfer to primary then either salvage the yeast or pour more beer straight on, depending on how well your brewing technique limits trub.